# Management of transactions and entityManager in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, entitymanager

I wonder how the transactions and the EntityManager are managed in Java EE.

If I understand, an EJB has an EntityManager, and an EntityManager has an EntityTransaction. Is it true ?

I have read this specification http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html and there something I don't understand. It is considered 2 beans ; my question is when the method of the bean-2 is annotated with "Required", how this bean can know if it exists a current transaction ? The entiyManager considered is different in the 2 beans, so the bean-2 cannot have access the object and the current transaction, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

In jee you could think of the container as a big brother who knows it ALL, in this case he knows what's going on with your transactions by introspecting your ejbs at deploy time and by using a proxy around them at runtime, when you look up or get by injection an ejb, what you get is not an instance of your ejb but a proxy with a reference to it, so when you invoke your ejbs you're actually invoking a proxy that will eventually invoke your ejb instance, this way the container keeps track of your transactions and everything else, and as any good big brother it can communicate with almost everything including all your entity managers in order to give them some context about the current transaction.

Keep in mind that the whole point of jee is that your ejbs don't have to know anything about transactions or anything else except the business, and as many things as possible get managed by the container. There's some good info [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31937&seqNum=2)